# Going through each element in a nested list

Tags: scheme

I am writing a procedure that removes strings from a nested list.
Example:

```
(define fubar '(("a" -1 7) (2 "c") ("d") (-2)))
(remove strings fubar) should return '((-1 7) (2) () (-2)).
```

Because you cannot simply `cdr` down the list since the lists are nested, you need a way to individually pick through every element of each list in order and check if there's a string. Any ideas on how to go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for traversing a list of lists follows a well-known template of a solution, I'll give you the general structure, so you can fill-in the blanks: it'll be much better if you find the solution by your own means!

```
(define (remove-strings lst)
  (cond (<???> <???>) ; if the list is empty, return the empty list
        ((not (pair? <???>)) ; if the current element is not a list
         (if (string? <???>) ; if the current element is a string
             (remove-strings <???>) ; simply advance recursion over cdr (*)
             (cons <???>                 ; else keep the current element
                  (remove-strings <???>)))) ; advance recursion over cdr
        (else                         ; otherwise it's a list of lists
         (cons (remove-strings <???>)     ; advance recursion over car
               (remove-strings <???>))))) ; advance recursion over cdr
```

Notice that in `(*)` we're "deleting" all strings we find by simply ignoring them in the process of constructing a new list, and in the next line, if it's not a string then we keep the element while building the output list. The above will work for arbitrarily nested lists.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a skeleton to get you started, The trick of a tree recursion is the recur on the car and cdr if the car is itself a list

```
(define (remove-strings fubar)
 (cond ((null? fubar) ...)
       ((pair? (car fubar)) 
        (cons (... (car fubar)) (... (cdr fubar))
       (else ...)))
```